# Using grepl() in R to match two consecutive words in a sentence (or: How to use wildcards in grepl())?

Tags: r, grepl

Suppose I would like to match two consecutive words in a sentence but explicitly not match other sentences that might still contain both of these words but not one right after the other.

```
mydata <- data.frame(text=c("I like pizza, and a read a novel.", "I like novels."))
```

So, if I do this...

```
grepl("lik.*? novel.*?", mydata$text, perl=T, ignore.case=T)
```

...I get "[1] TRUE TRUE", while what I need is "FALSE TRUE" given that "like" in the first sentence doesn't refer to "novel".

Now, this might be a bad example, given that I could simply search for "Like novel.*?" without a wildcard for the first word, but suppose further that I need to use this wildcard for the first of the two words, too.

And connected to that: How would one match a word in a sentence with a wildcard in the middle of said word?

Example:

```
mydata<-data.frame(text=c("xxx abc xxx", "xxx azc xxx", "xxx a bc xxx"))
```

I would like to match words that start with "a" and end with "c" no matter what comes in between but the condition is that this must be one word. Currently, I get a "TRUE" even for the third line while what I would need is a match for the first two but not for the third:

```
grepl("a.*?c", mydata$text, perl=T, ignore.case=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the words are consecutive

```
grepl("like\\b \\bnovel", mydata$text, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

and for second case, we can usse the word boundary (`\\b`) at the beginning and end of

```
grepl("\\ba\\w+c\\b", mydata$text, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Here the pattern to match is a word boundary (`\\b`) followed by character 'a', one or more characters (`\\w+`) and 'c' followed by word boundary (`\\b`)

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! So '\\w+\' is for any number of characters _within_ a word? How would I specify that there can be literally anything between 'a' and 'b', even a number? Can I use `*` or `.*?` for that? Do you know of any cheat sheet out there about how to specify conditions for matching with grepl? The grep/ grepl documentation PDF is not particularly helpful in this regard...

Comment: @FabianHabersack  You can use `\\ba[A-Za-z0-9]+c\\b` or `\\ba[^ ]+c\\b` (not a space

Comment: @FabianHabersack  It may be better to check https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html for more understanding of the regex

Comment: @FabianHabersack `"like\\b \\bnovel"` = `"like novel"`. Word boundary between `e` and space and space and `n` is implicit. `\w` matches digits and `_`, too.

Comment: Okay thank you! Guess I need to learn more about regular expressions...

Comment: Brief question: if `+` is for 1+ matches (as opposed to `*` which is for 0+), why does `"\\ba\\w+c\\b"` still match this: `"xxx ac xxx"` even though there is nothing in between a and c (i.e. no digit or underscore)?

Comment: @FabianHabersack  It is not matching for me `grepl("\\ba\\w+c\\b","xxx ac xxx", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)#
[1] FALSE`